# How to access choice from form in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have following form builder:

```
$builder->add('status', 'choice', array('attr' => array(
            'choices' => array('0' => 'Principal', '1' => 'Teacher', '2' => 'Student'),
            'required' => true, 'expanded' => 'false', 'multiple' => 'true'
          )));
```

How to present those 3 values as radio buttons in twig template in a way like below presented(it doesn't work)?

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form.status.choices[0]) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want radio buttons you need change options to `'expanded' => 'true', 'multiple' => 'false'`

[image]

In twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form.status) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**More information:** [choice Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)